# Why IEnumerable slow and List is fast?

Tags: c#, linq

Came across this code.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for(int i=0; i<20000; i++)
{
    dic.Add(i, i.ToString());
}

var list = dic.Where(f => f.Value.StartsWith("1")).Select(f => f.Key);//.ToList(); //uncomment for fast results 
Console.WriteLine(list.GetType());
var list2 = dic.Where(f => list.Contains(f.Key)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(list2.Count());
```

So when .ToList() is commented it's slow, when not - it's fast. Reproducable [here](http://rextester.com/SYPD34574) How could this be explained? Should I always make everything ToList() to ensure speed (i.e. in which circumstances IEnumerable would be more preferable)? Note I'm talking only about linq to objects, I know linq to sql laziness and stuff.

Comment: How are you checking the time?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn wall clock

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because of *deferred execution*: when you comment out `ToList`, the enumeration is produced by evaluating the sequence of filters for each item in the dictionary. When you do a `ToList`, however, the sequence is "materialized" in memory, so all the evaluations are performed exactly once.

The logic behind the second `Where` without `ToList` looks like this:

```
// The logic is expanded for illustration only.
var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
foreach (var d in dict) {
    var list = new List<int>();
    // This nested loop does the same thing on each iteration,
    // redoing n times what could have been done only once.
    foreach (var f in dict) {
        if (f.Value.StartsWith("1")) {
            list.Add(f.Key);
        }
    }
    if (list.Contains(d.Key)) {
        list2.Add(d);
    }
}
```

The logic with `ToList` looks like this:

```
// The list is prepared once, and left alone
var list = new List<int>();
foreach (var f in dict) {
    if (f.Value.StartsWith("1")) {
        list.Add(f.Key);
    }
}
var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
// This loop uses the same list in all its iterations.
foreach (var d in dict) {
    if (list.Contains(d.Key)) {
        list2.Add(d);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `ToList` transforms an `O(n^2)` program with two nested loops of size `n` into `O(2*n)` with two sequential loops of size `n` each.

Answer (score 15):

LINQ uses *deferred execution*.
Unless you call `.ToList()`, the results of a query are never stored anywhere; instead, it re-iterates the query every time you iterate the results.

Normally, this is much faster; there is usually no reason to store all of the results in memory first.

However, your code repeatedly iterates the query; once for each call to the `Where()` callback.

You should replace that line with a `Join()` call and no `ToList()`, which will be faster than either approach.

Comment: How would Join() be used in this context?

Comment: @DovMiller I got an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835599/how-to-replace-tolist-with-join

Answer (score 3):

Because when you don't have the `.ToList()` call, the `list2` instantiation will iterate through the whole `list` enumerable for every item in the dictionary.  So you go from O(n) to O(n^2) if you use deferred execution.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by deferred execution.
IEnumerable does not has to be a static collection. Generaly it is some data source (`dic` in your case) + all methods and expressions (Where, Contains, etc.) that lead to the final set.

.ToList() executes all these methods and expressions and generates the final result.

So in case you use ToList() it generates a standard .NET List (array of integers) and does all operations on that list.

If you don´t call ToList() (or any other To-method) the IEnumerable can be enumerated several times.